# How to load images in S3 for a deep learning model with EC2 instance (GPU)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, keras

I'm trying to train a Keras model on AWS GPU.

How would you load images (training data) in S3 for a deep learning model with EC2 instance (GPU)?

Comment: look at the boto3 library and the S3 api for it

Answer (score 1):

I use [FileZilla Pro](https://filezilla-project.org/) (10 USD) which is cross platform and gives you a very easy and fast FTP like experience.

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=de) is cross platform too and works great as well from my experience.

You might also want to look at [Mountainduck](https://mountainduck.io/) or [Tntrive](https://tntdrive.com/) if you want to directly mount S3 buckets on Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using Jupyter notebook otherwise use:

Duck for MAC, Putty for windows.

I hope it helps

Comment: I used Jupyter notebook to upload jpg images. I first compress the images in zip file and then on the ec2 instance you cna install unzip and load your images to a folder.